# Considering the C++ program below, what should be inserted in place of //***** to ensure a 100% clean shutdown?

Tags: c++, clog

This is an exam question:

> Considering the C++ program below, what should be inserted in place of
>   `//*****` to ensure a 100% clean shutdown?
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>     using namespace std;
>
>     fstream log("log.txt", ios::out);
>     streambuf* clog_buf = clog.rdbuf(log.rdbuf());
>
>     clog << "Test the logger" << endl;
>
>     //*****
> }
> ```
>
> - A. Nothing is missing.
> - B. exit();
> - C. clog.rdbuf(clog_buf);
> - D. clog.rdbuf(0);
> - E. log.rdbuf(0);

I am rather confused on the use of `log` and `clog` in this code. Why can't we just create a file and write down everything we need? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: You've got two (`clog` and `log`) streams both owning the same `streambuf`. What happens when the streams go out of scope?

Comment: Asking for the answer to an exam question (even if you've already handed your exam in) in the middle of exam season seems like a poor choice. Perhaps you could/should ask your instructor instead?

Comment: Typical exam question. In real life you'd go to cppreference.com or check your Strousup book to make sure you used the API correctly. Because often when you believe you are doing it correctly, you aren't.

Comment: @datenwolf: You haven't corrected it yet. Both "the compiler will probably warn" and "a return statement is definitely missing" are untrue. `main` is a special case.

Comment: @datenwolf Returning from main is not identical to calling exit.

Comment: The code runs very well on VS 2008 even though without return value. I think return value is the point of this question.

Comment: @fizzer: I'll just delete my comment. No so important anyway :)

Comment: @user3092410: I'm pretty sure it's not the point of this question, not least because _none_ of the available answers say anything at all about a return value.

Answer (score 2):

`clog_buf` points to the stream buffer that clog pointed to before you reset it with `rdbuf`. A clean shutdown can be achieved by resetting clog's stream buffer to what it was before by using C ( `clog.rdbuf( clog_buf );` ).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But on VS 2008, the code without "clog.rdbuf(clog_buf);" runs well. How do I test if it is a clean shutdown?

Comment: You can call 'clog << "Test Message";' and see if it appears in your terminal as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The code is swapping the standard `clog` stream (which initially works on STDERR) for a file stream. It means that any code anywhere in the program that streams to `clog` will actually now stream to a file instead. It's a good *localised* way to redirect log output, which doesn't require search/replacing ten million utterances of the text `clog` in your source code.

The answer is **C**, which reverts the `clog` stream back to the way you found it before the implicit `return 0` kicks in and the program ends gracefully, including the normal file stream destruction.

`exit()` is a non-graceful shutdown which would not close your file stream properly.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not appear to be exception safe.
Therefore, in the face of exceptions, none of the answers will ensure a 100% clean shutdown.